# ECU Throwing an error for CPS despite changing it

Tags: honda, civic, crank-position-sensor

So a while back I had the ECU throw a check engine code for the crankshaft position sensor, I changed both the camshaft and crankshaft sensors for ones that I got off a used car from the junkyard. A few months later the car took a while to start and the engine started rev limiting at 3.5k and threw P0335 code. This time I bought a brand new crankshaft position sensor and did a complete timing job. After starting the car it immediately threw a check engine light with the code P0335 and had the rev limitter again at 3.5k. The wiring harness while has some wear on it definitely does not look corroded. Why would the engine be throwing the CPS light again? I tried removing the negative terminal of the battery to reset it but it started with the code immediately again

Few things to say, I still have not assembled the rest of the engine. Currently, the harmonic balancer/crank pulley is still off, could that cause the CPS not to detect the location of the crank? The alternator is also off the vehicle (running on battery juice) but the battery light is not on for some reason.

The vehicle is a 2005 Honda Civic HX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently, the harmonic balancer/crank pulley is still off, could that
>   cause the CPS not to detect the location of the crank?

Er, yes.  The Crank Position Sensor is a hall effect device and it generally reads off a tooth or some other indicator on the balancer (possibly a small magnet?)

[image: crank position sensor]

disclaimer: my note here is generic in nature... and not specific to your make and model.  I've worked on more than a whole lot of cars.  These all work essentially the same for vehicle in the past 30 years or so...

Question for you: When you first turn the key to 'ON' before starting the engine, is there the alternator / charging light visible in the instrument cluster?

Comment: When I read the wikipedia page on the CPS it did mention that some of them read off the reluctor ring on the harmonic balancer and mentioned that it was in some GM family cars but I do not think in this engine that it does that. I am going to put the harmonic balancer just in case and test. And to answer your question yes the battery light turns on when the ignition is ON but not when it is running

Comment: UPDATE: zipzit was correct, the CPS does read off the harmonic balancer and the code went away and the car functioned fine after I installed it. Further, I was also wrong, the battery light did not come on because it didn't even come on when it was in ignition as I previously thought. When I connected the alternator plug it now turns and functions as it should. Thank you!